# RAILS & Javascript issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm probably doing something stupid here but for some reason i can't seem to figure it out. Just need someone to point out what i'm doing wrong.

Basically, i'm looping through images in this div. They are images of the same object, just different views.

```
<div class="ind">
 <%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
   <%= image_tag product.secimage_url(:index).to_s, class: 'current' %>
   <%= image_tag product.image_url(:index).to_s, class: 'product' %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

`'current'` is the second view that should show on `:hover` of `'product'`

CSS code

```
.product {
position: relative;
top: 0;
}

.current {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
}
```

Javascript code

```
var main = function() {
$('.product').hover(function() {
$(this).hide(1);
});

$('.current').mouseleave(function() {
$('.product').show(1);  
}); 
};
```

I have managed to hide one behind the other and when you hover, it shows the second view BUT, due to the `relative` and `absolute` in CSS, the other elements on the page end up moving and the page gets disorganised.

Looking for a solution that would do the same thing without messing up the layout of other objects.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by changing the image class names to `image` and added a `hide` class to the secondary image so it starts off hidden.

Because there were other pictures being generated by the rails loop, the first answer toggled all the images at once. So i used a javascript loop over the parent `div` and it worked.

Here's the new code

```
<div class="ind">
<%= link_to product_path(product) do %>
  <%= image_tag product.secimage_url(:index).to_s, class: "image hide" %>
  <%= image_tag product.image_url(:index).to_s, class: "image" %>
<% end %>
```

Javascript code

```
var toggleProductImage = function() {
$(this).children().each(function() {
this.classList.toggle('hide');
})
}

$('.ind a').each(function() {
$(this).mouseenter(toggleProductImage);
$(this).mouseleave(toggleProductImage);
});
```

CSS

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}

.image {
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
}

.ind {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set the default one you want hidden to `style: "display: none;"` or if you have a `hide` class. Then add a toggle class of whatever name you feel relevant to both and do

```
  $(".toggle").mouseover(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggle();
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggle();
  });;
```

The reason for the toggle class is if you put it on mouseover for .current and another for .product it will toggle rapidly between both. You want need any of the positions etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works, but it is a store so all the other images also change with the one you hover. Trying to make sure only the image being hovered changes...